# SwiftUI alternate views - Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two reusable views, Ex1 and Ex2. I am trying to show one of them depends on a condition alternately but I could not it.

ContentvIew:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var selector = false
    var cvc = ContentViewController()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack { // ERROR: Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

            cvc.getView(t: selector)

            Button(action: {
                self.selector.toggle()
                print(self.selector)
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
        }
}
```

Ex1 :

```
import SwiftUI

struct Ex1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Ex 1")
    }
}
```

Ex2 :

```
import SwiftUI

struct Ex2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Ex 2")
    }
}
```

ContentViewController :

```
import Foundation

class ContentViewController {

    let a = Ex1()
    let b = Ex2()

    func getView (t: Bool) ->(Any){
        if t {
            return a
        }
        else {
            return b
        }
    }
}
```

I think it is very simple but not for me, for now. Help for two things, please.

1. I want to understand this problem, and the solution.
2. Best way for alternate two view in a layout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests the return type specified in `ContentViewController`'s `getView` method does not conform to the protocols.

In SwiftUI everything you specified in `body{}` clause must be a type of `View` if you do not know what kind of view available at runtime.

You can specify `AnyView` type for unknown views.

So your error will be removed by changing the `ContentViewController`'s code.

```
class ContentViewController {

    let a = Ex1()
    let b = Ex2()

    func getView (t: Bool) -> (AnyView) {
        if t {
            return AnyView(a)
        }
        else {
            return AnyView(b)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Kampai. It worked. (after adding "import SwiftUI").

Comment: Great answer thanks! Maybe worth mentioning that this essentially type erases the view